# Javascript & jQuery: how to make function infinite through animate callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

have an object of a class `Abon` and then i want this object to move around the page.

```
a = new Abon();
a.init();
a.move();
```

the method `move()` contains:

```
function abon_move () {
  var x = this.x;
  var y = this.y;

  var direction_x = Math.random()*5 - 5;
  var direction_y = Math.random()*5 - 5;

  var x_new = x + direction_x * this.movement_rate;
  var y_new = y + direction_y * this.movement_rate;
  console.log(x_new+" "+y_new)
  $(".abonent."+this.id).animate( {
        left:+x_new,
        top:+y_new
    }, 'slow', "linear", function() { this.move() });
}
```

All i want is that the method `move` (represented as function `abon_move()`) repeated again and again, after the `animate` stops. But the problem is that `this.move()` shown in callback has no connection to my object, because `this` in that place points to the HTML element, selected by jQuery.

UPD:

```
 function Abon(id) {
   ...
this.move = abon_move;
   ...
 }
 Abon.prototype.move = abon_move;
```

And the actual method is the same, but with no callback in `animate`

then i try doing the following:

```
 setInterval( a[0].move , 300); //doesn't work - says `this` members are undefined
 setInterval( a[0].move() , 300); //works only one time and stops
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
function abon_move () {
    var x = this.x;
    var y = this.y;
    var class = this;
    ...

}
```

Then, inside your jQuery `animate`, your can refer to your class using the variable `class`

Comment: just what i was looking for =)

Comment: actually, I made a mistake. I believe `class` is a reserved keyword in JS, but you can use any other name

Comment: aw, i thought it was necessary to use `class`, anyway it worked, thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the function `abon_move()` in a `setTimeout` call, as such: `setTimeout(abon_move, 300);` so it will run every 300 ms.

Comment: in fact there will be an array of objects. And i don't really understand it now. I created another method, that contains: `setTimeout(abon_move, 300);` only, and `abon_move()` doesn't work, because i have no connection to `this`

Comment: Ok, but put the move function in Abon. eg `Abon.prototype.move = function() {}`. Then you'll have access to `this`. Then do your timer as an event loop, such as `setTimeout(function() { for (a in array_of_abons) { a.move(); }, 300);`.

Comment: tried it, have no result. Could you please look at the update i posted in original message